# onclick=document.getElementById can't find id

Tags: javascript, html

I'm very new to Javascript and one of the buttons I created can't seem to find the id it's looking for.

```
<button type="button" onclick=document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "replacement text">English</button>
<button type="button" onclick='document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "replacement text"'>Nederlands</button>

<p class=text id=text>
```

the first onclick can't find the id from the

and I don't know why. the class=text is used for CSS. If any of you would be so kind to answer what's wrong. It would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just a word of caution, make sure the text is safe from harmful code injection. in other words: it's better to use `.innerText = str` instead of `.innerHTML = str` whenever possible

Answer (score 1):

You have missing quotes in your first `button`'s `onclick` handler:

```html
<button type="button" onclick='document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "replacement text English"'>English</button>
<button type="button" onclick='document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "replacement text Nederlands"'>Nederlands</button>

<p class="text" id="text">original text</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add quotes and better practice to end tag `<p>`:

```
<button type="button" onclick='document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "replacement text"'>English</button>
<button type="button" onclick='document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "replacement text"'>Nederlands</button>

<p class=text id=text></p>
```

---

Another `class` attribute in `p` tag is of no use, as you aren't using any CSS or using Javascript to handle it.